# Testing actual in-app purchases; locking gmail acct access?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app

So, I used a specific gmail account to do purchase and refund/credit live transaction testing. I did this about 13 times or so within a four hour block yesterday. Now I get the error below in logcat and I also get an error (Your order could not be processed) when I attempt to do a purchase in-app.

```
03-22 09:01:14.258: D/Finsky(2025): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode: Sending response RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE for request 6343763957627128114 to kenyu73.bannerwidget.
```

I have another app installed on the same device (nexus) and it's working fine with the same in-app code.

I also have a different test gmail account on a Fascinate that seems to be fine too.

I think my email account that I used to do live testing is blocked for the app I tested with.

Comment: uhm...that doesn't seem an error. Could you post your error please?

Comment: Its not technically an error, but the in-app functionality will not work. It will not initialize nor will the in-app Market allow a purchase.

Comment: I'm almost 99% sure that the Market has my email blocked for this one app because of the spammed test transactions. It's only my gmail on this ONE single app that is giving the error response. My other app works fine. I also had a friend test with his Nexus and its fine. I'm hoping the "ban" is automatically lifted, but it doesn't matter because its only my (1) app/email nothing else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like my in-app was blocked for that specific app/in-app combination. I was able initialize a few hours later without any changes on my side (besides an email to Google).